# Is using multiple for loops compared to one for loop more memory and time costly in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, memory, time, memory-management

What's more time and memory efficient in Matlab?

I am writing the pseudo code.

**1)**

```
for:
 Open a file
 Read the temperature info
 find the min max and avg temperature value;
for:
 Open a file
 Read the voltage info
 find the min max and avg voltage value;
for:
 Open a file
 Read the resistence info
 find the min max and avg resistence value;
```

OR the code below?

**2)**

```
for:
 Open a file
 Read the temperature info
 find the min max and avg temperature value
 Open a file
 Read the voltage info
 find the min max and avg voltage value
 Open a file
 Read the resistence info
 find the min max and avg resistence value;
```

Comment: This cannot be answered, the only way to know for sure what takes less time is implementing both and comparing. But it is likely that “open a file” and “read from file” are the more expensive operation here. Loops are not inherently expensive, but what you do inside is repeated many times, which is what causes people to say that loops are expensive.

Comment: Do you really have all this info in individual little files? Or are you opening and reading from the same file multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

There should be little difference between the two implementations both in terms of time and memory. The only difference between them is reusing the loop variable, which is negligible.

Btw MATLAB has JIT now so loop itself is not costly anymore (which was many years ago).